# WPF C# Unable to remove item from Listview (ItemsSource is in use)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a listview that I want to remove items from after I perform certain background tasks. From my background_dowork, I call this:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
{
    FilesList.Items.RemoveAt(FilesList.Items.IndexOf(selectedFile));
    FilesList.UpdateLayout();
}));
```

selectedFile is an Item within the FilesList.

However, when the dispatcher runs, I get an exception that the itemsource is in use?

How can I remove the item from the list?

This is how I created FilesList:

```
InputFile inputItem = new InputFile
{
    FileName = f[i].Name,
    FilePath = f[i].FullName
};
lif.Add(inputItem);
FilesList.ItemsSource = lif;
```

Comment: You should remove the item from the `ItemsSource`.

Comment: How do I do that? ItemsSource doesnt have a remove.

Comment: Cast it. See my answer.

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't directly access an UI Element in this case, but directly pass your list "lif" to the background worker and do all the changes to the collection on that list. The UI will update automaticall (given you're using an observableCollection and not a normal List, which you should for Collections that change and are used in the UI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the item from the `ItemsSource`:

```
var itemsSource = FilesList.ItemsSource as IList<YourClass>();
if (itemsSource != null)
    itemsSource.Remove(selectedFile);
```

Note that you need to set the `ItemsSource` to an `ObservableCollection<T>`, or a custom collection that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, for the it to get removed from the view without you having to refresh it explicitly, i.e. removing an item from a `List<T>` won't update the view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this update the list as well?

Comment: Yes, that exactly what it does.

Comment: I just tried it. My list still has the item though. I also added a updatelayout.

Comment: Did you read my answer? It won't work with a List<T>.

Comment: It works if I set the list to null and re-add the itemsource. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's what you need to do if you are using a List<T> and it's not MVVM. Therefore you should use an ObservableCollection<T>.